# Django Form Dynamic Fields looping over each field from POST and creating records

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for some advice where to go from here. I've been working on making a Form, which dynamically generates its fields.

The form is working and generating everything correctly. However, I am having issues with how to save the actual form data. I'm looking for each field to save as a new item in a model.

***The View Class from view.py***

```
class MaintenanceCheckListForm(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
login_url = '/accounts/login'
template_name = 'maintenance/checklist.html'
form_class = MaintenanceCheckListForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('m-checklist')

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.cleaned_data
    for key, values in form:
            MaintenanceCheckList.objects.create(
                item = key,
                is_compliant = values
        )
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

***The Form from forms.py***

```
class MaintenanceCheckListForm(forms.Form):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MaintenanceCheckListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    items = Maintenance_Item.objects.all()

    CHOICES = (
        ('P','Compliant'),
        ('F','Non-Compliant'),
    )

    for item in items:
            self.fields[str(item.name)] = forms.ChoiceField(
            label=item.name,
            choices=CHOICES,
            widget=forms.RadioSelect,
            initial='F',
        )
```

***The Model, from models.py***

```
class MaintenanceCheckList(CommonInfo):
CHOICES = (
    ('P','Compliant'),
    ('F','Non-Compliant'),
)

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
is_compliant = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices= CHOICES)
```

I am having trouble accessing the data from the Form when it POST's. I've done some troubleshooting where I have set the values statically in the '''form_valid''' and it appears to generate the correct amounts of entires in the model. However the trouble begins when I attempt to insert the values from the POST.

I receieve the below error, which I believe it is trying to dump all the keys and values into a single item instead of looping over each key, value and creating the item.

```
DataError at /maintenance/checklist
value too long for type character varying(100)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://t1.localhost:8000/maintenance/checklist
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: DataError
Exception Value:    
value too long for type character varying(100)
```

I'm fairly new to the world of Django (4 weeks and counting so far, and maybe 12 weeks into python). So any assistance would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have somewhat gone on a tangent. There's a simpler solution of using [Model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) for what you want.

First if you want a custom form make that:

```
from django import forms


class MaintenanceCheckListComplianceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    item = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())
    is_compliant = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=MaintenanceCheckList.CHOICES,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        initial='F',
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = MaintenanceCheckList
        fields = ('item', 'is_compliant')
```

Next use it along with `modelformset_factory` in your views:

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory


class MaintenanceCheckListFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView): # Changed view name was a bit misleading
    login_url = '/accounts/login'
    template_name = 'maintenance/checklist.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('m-checklist')
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        instances = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['queryset'] = MaintenanceCheckList.objects.none()
        kwargs['initial'] = [{'item': obj['name'], 'is_compliant': 'F'} for obj in Maintenance_Item.objects.all().values('name')]
        return kwargs
    
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        extra = len(kwargs['initial'])
        form_class = modelformset_factory(MaintenanceCheckList, form=MaintenanceCheckListComplianceForm, extra=extra)
        return form_class(**kwargs)
```

Now in your template:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Or manually render it:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for sub_form in form %}
        Item: {{ sub_form.item.value }}
        {{ sub_form }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**Note**: The above usage is a bit weird due to the naming of the formset variable as `form` by the `FormView` you should look into improving that a bit.

**Note**: Looking at the implementation it feels a bit weird to do this. I would advice you to redesign your models a bit. Perhaps a foreign key between your models? It basically feels like you have duplicate data with this implementation.

Comment: Hi Abdul, originally, I did investigate Formsets, however my concern was making this form dynamic based upon the number of items in the Maintenance Item List. I personally couldn't find the way to do this formsets, I did spend a few days trying. If you could explain to me, how this code above would achieve that it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BrytonWishart oh didn't notice you wanted to use the other models instances. Thought you wanted to update all `MaintenanceCheckList` instances. The answer would need some editing.

Comment: fully understand, I didn't highlight that clearly in my above code, but in the '__init__ 'of the form, I pull from another model to generate each field on the form. Hence why i went down the rabbit hole of the custom Form instead of using Formsets.

I did try to do an 'extra=len(items)' and item variable was just a 'objects.all()' and used a 'model_to_dict', to let me create a directory to initial each form in the formset, but i just couldn't get it.

Comment: Looking at this code, I can't see how it is going to generate a Form for each object in the Maintenance_Item model. With Formsets, do we not have to define an `extra=` variable which would have to equal the `len` of the model items? In terms of the FK between Maintenance_Items, orginally I did have a FK relationship but just removed when I was doing some other testing. Ideally this checklist is completed daily and would be kept for compliance reasons.

Comment: @BrytonWishart fixed that :).  Also we do pass the form for each instance the default implementation of `get_form` calls `get_form_kwargs` to get the kwargs for the form (overrided that in this edit).

Comment: I think I understand, we have moved the formset_factory into the get_form, and this is where we are doing our Formset construction, based upon the kwargs which we have called from the Maintenance_items in the get_form_kwargs. Just going back to normalisation of the model. I went down the rabbit hole of compliance and wanting to ensure the data in this Model, wasn't impacted by someone deleting an item from Maintenace_Item. Which i why i origanlly removed the FK relationship. If you have an better idea around this, I would love your input.

Comment: @BrytonWishart How about setting `on_delete=models.PROTECT` on the foreign key and having some extra field in the other model like `is_active` or something to indicate whether it is used or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229290/discussion-between-bryton-wishart-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).